# Unable to use JAR file when running a java file

Tags: java, jdbc, jar

I've been trying to use a JAR file ("sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar") in my java program when running it via the command prompt, but no matter which way I try to specify it with the -classpath flag, it just won't work.
Through I command prompt I ran:

`javac -classpath ".\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" myProgram.java`

and then:

`java -classpath ".\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" myProgram.java`

And my program keeps returning the exception:

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:[My db file path]`

I also tried using the -classpath flag like so:

`-classpath ".;.\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"`

but this yields the same result.

Note that I did make the same program work with the JAR file via Eclipse, but I really prefer not to use Eclipse. I'd like to understand why it won't simply work with the command prompt.

Comment: I assume the path you are referencing within your classpath actually exists. Java does not emit errors when adding non-existent files or folders to the classpath. However, you can add `DriverManager.setLogWriter(/*something useful*/)` at some point in your code to get some debug logging for Java's JDBC driver discovery.

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment.
Actually, a minute ago I downloaded the latest xerial\sqlite-jdbc jar file from GitHub and it magically works now, when using the -classpath flag to specify that jar file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

I downloaded the latest xerial\sqlite-jdbc jar file from GitHub and it magically works now, when using the -classpath flag to specify that jar file.